# Filter values of list from list indexes

Tags: python, list, indexing

For a list of list, I have written a function that returns the indexes for which the written condition is true:

```
samples_avg = [[1, 12, 3], [15000, 4, 3], [1, 144, 45]]

def check(samples_avg, tracker):

out = [[] for _ in samples_avg]
for indx, v in enumerate(zip(*samples_avg)):
    m = max((val, i, indx) for i, val in enumerate(v))
    if all(val * 5 < m[0] for i, val in enumerate(v) if i != m[1]):
        out[m[1]].extend([m[2]])
print (out)
```

Output:
    `out = [[], [0], [1, 2]]`

However I would like to add the function for this list to return the element at the true index from another list. So from the above `out`, for a list like this:

```
tracker = ['meow', 'woof', 'quack', 'where', 'what', 'who', 'dont', 'call', 'me']
```

I would expect this output:

```
g = [[], ['meow'], ['woof', 'quack']]
```

to do this I have written:

```
samples_avg = [[1, 12, 3], [15000, 4, 3], [1, 144, 45]]
tracker = ['meow', 'woof', 'quack', 'where', 'what', 'who', 'dont', 'call', 'me']

def check(samples_avg, tracker):

out = [[] for _ in samples_avg]
g = [[] for _ in out]
for indx, v in enumerate(zip(*samples_avg)):
    m = max((val, i, indx) for i, val in enumerate(v))
    if all(val * 5 < m[0] for i, val in enumerate(v) if i != m[1]):
        out[m[1]].extend([m[2]])
        g = [[t for i in o] for t, o in zip(tracker, out)]
print (out)
print (g)
```

However, this returns:

```
g = [[], ['woof'], ['quack', 'quack']]
```

How can I fix this? Any advice would be appreciate!

Comment: Beware: you are modifying a list that you are then iterating over. don't do that:
            out[m[1]].extend([m[2]])

Answer (score 0):

You just need a list comprehension like the following for this.

```
out = [[], [0], [1, 2]]
tracker = ['meow', 'woof', 'quack', 'where', 'what', 'who', 'dont', 'call', 'me']

[[tracker[i] for i in arr] for arr in out]
```

**Result:**

```
[[], ['meow'], ['woof', 'quack']]
```

You probably want this outside the `if` statement in your function.